# Enterprise Library Validation Application Block. How to validate the model class?

Tags: asp.net, validation, enterprise-library

I am using [Enterprise Library 5.0 - Validation Application Block 5.0.505.0](http://nuget.org/packages/EnterpriseLibrary.Validation) in my project. I have modified my Model class attributes with the validation annotations (like NotNullValidator). But when I run my project and fill the particular Model class with data, it does not automatically validate the Model. Do I have to test the Model manually as below?

```
USAddress testaddress = new USAddress(); //this is the Model instance which I am validating

        //Create a new validator using the ValidationFactory method
        Validator validator = ValidationFactory.CreateValidator<USAddress>();
        ValidationResults results = new ValidationResults();
        validator.Validate(testaddress, results);
```

Do I have to validate the Model class like this everytime? Doesn't it get automatically validated when I fill the data to the attributes of this class?

Answer (score 1):

Validation with models should use:

```
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
```

You need to make references to:

```
System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations
```

You will then have access to attributes like:

```
[Required]
[StringLength]
[RegularExpression]
[Compare]
```

[Required] is similar to the [NotNullValidator].

HTH!